Can't get session on useSession client nextauth status still "unauthenticated"
I'm using NextAuth v4 in my Next.js project, and I have implemented the useSession hook to get the session status. However, the status always returns "unauthenticated", even though I have successfully signed in.
This error where i get
[next-auth][debug][adapter_getSessionAndUser] {
  args: [
    'eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0..au_5WrvErMWaDqNR.daHfdu23NkBrcXQn_HwmgyypBid2mCU6qP_IouMn5Ovf7TWP70bggVNplp0K3H6wwcUnMEZANE2mTF24nc-J8Nagel7AVlugb39vmqfv3WsFhdSdinzLMn4pMtvXB_UJ9MTIl-h9SvjN2jh_6g-lKwzxXmWv1dEkQdvXfZx9Ig6WurT2rG0Wgoxu-_PF_totLgEg6xubDGXqWvr2eAdOqg1-F5Ohwf2YegZMtQ-FZ2m5n5Kvy6vCE9di7SrX2sU.qJJkyQ0HKkMSrfctnOqKLQ'
  ]
}
[next-auth][error][adapter_error_getSessionAndUser]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#adapter_error_getsessionanduser Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findUnique') {
  message: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findUnique')",
  stack: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findUnique')\n" +
    '    at getSessionAndUser (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\.next\\server\\chunks\\node_modules_4c1078._.js:5510:52)\n' +
    '    at _callee2$ (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\.next\\server\\chunks\\node_modules_4c1078._.js:6699:39)\n' +
    '    at tryCatch (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\.next\\server\\chunks\\node_modules_4c1078._.js:5934:24)\n' +
    '    at Generator.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\.next\\server\\chunks\\node_modules_4c1078._.js:6021:25)\n' +
    '    at Generator.next (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\.next\\server\\chunks\\node_modules_4c1078._.js:5962:29)\n' +
    '    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\.next\\server\\chunks\\node_modules_4c1078._.js:6259:21)\n' +
    '    at _next `your text`(C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\.next\\server\\chunks\\node_modules_4c1078._.js:6271:17)\n' +
    '    at `your text`C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\.next\\server\\chunks\\node_modules_4c1078._.js:6276:13\n' +
    '    at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n' +
    '    at C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\.next\\server\\chunks\\node_modules_4c1078._.js:6268:16\n' +
    '    at Object.session (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\.next\\server\\chunks\\node_modules_4c1078._.js:19982:40)\n' +
    '    at AuthHandler (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\.next\\server\\chunks\\node_modules_4c1078._.js:21986:50)\n' +
    '    at async NextAuthRouteHandler (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\.next\\server\\chunks\\node_modules_4c1078._.js:24487:30)\n' +
    '    at async NextAuth._args$ (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\.next\\server\\chunks\\node_modules_4c1078._.js:24522:24)\n' +
    '    at async AppRouteRouteModule.do (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\next-server\\app-route.runtime.dev.js:10:33313)\n' +
    '    at async AppRouteRouteModule.handle (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\next-server\\app-route.runtime.dev.js:10:40382)\n' +
    '    at async doRender (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\base-server.js:1455:42)\n' +
    '    at async responseGenerator (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\base-server.js:1814:28)\n' +
    '    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\base-server.js:1824:28)\n' +
    '    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\base-server.js:2240:24)\n' +      
    '    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\base-server.js:2278:32)\n' +     
    '    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\base-server.js:960:25)\n' +
    '    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\next-server.js:281:17)\n' +
    '    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\base-server.js:853:17)\n' +
    '    at async C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\dev\\next-dev-server.js:373:20\n' +
    '    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\trace\\trace.js:153:20)\n' +
    '    at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\dev\\next-dev-server.js:370:24)\n' +    
    '    at async invokeRender (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\lib\\router-server.js:183:21)\n' +
    '    at async handleRequest (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\lib\\router-server.js:360:24)\n' +
    '    at async requestHandlerImpl (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\lib\\router-server.js:384:13)\n' +
    '    at async Server.requestListener (C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Project\\everse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\lib\\start-server.js:142:13)',
  name: 'TypeError'
}
[next-auth][error][SESSION_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#session_error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findUnique') Error [GetSessionAndUserError]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findUnique')
    at getSessionAndUser (file://C%3A/Users/ACER/Documents/Project/everse/node_modules/%40auth/prisma-adapter/index.js:25:51)
    at _callee2$ (file://C%3A/Users/ACER/Documents/Project/everse/node_modules/next-auth/core/errors.js:236:26)
    at tryCatch (file://C%3A/Users/ACER/Documents/Project/everse/node_modules/%40babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:45:15)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (file://C%3A/Users/ACER/Documents/Project/everse/node_modules/%40babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:133:16)
    at Generator.next (file://C%3A/Users/ACER/Documents/Project/everse/node_modules/%40babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:74:20)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (file://C%3A/Users/ACER/Documents/Project/everse/node_modules/%40babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:17)
    at _next (file://C%3A/Users/ACER/Documents/Project/everse/node_modules/%40babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:8)
    at <unknown> (file://C%3A/Users/ACER/Documents/Project/everse/node_modules/%40babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:6)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at <unknown> (file://C%3A/Users/ACER/Documents/Project/everse/node_modules/%40babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:14:11)
    at Object.session (file://C%3A/Users/ACER/Documents/Project/everse/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/session.js:89:33)
    at AuthHandler (file://C%3A/Users/ACER/Documents/Project/everse/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:136:39)
    at async NextAuthRouteHandler (file://C%3A/Users/ACER/Documents/Project/everse/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:57:27)
    at async NextAuth._args$ (file://C%3A/Users/ACER/Documents/Project/everse/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:89:15)
    at async AppRouteRouteModule.do (webpack://next/dist/src/server/route-modules/app-route/module.ts:529:14)
    at async AppRouteRouteModule.handle (webpack://next/dist/src/server/route-modules/app-route/module.ts:658:30)
    at async doRender (node_modules\next\src\server\base-server.ts:2504:29)      
    at async responseGenerator (node_modules\next\src\server\base-server.ts:3027:21)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (node_modules\next\src\server\base-server.ts:3039:23)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (node_modules\next\src\server\base-server.ts:3597:15)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (node_modules\next\src\server\base-server.ts:3659:23)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (node_modules\next\src\server\base-server.ts:1698:20)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (node_modules\next\src\server\next-server.ts:1034:6)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (node_modules\next\src\server\base-server.ts:1462:8)
    at async (node_modules\next\src\server\dev\next-dev-server.ts:514:13)        
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (node_modules\next\src\trace\trace.ts:143:13)     
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (node_modules\next\src\server\dev\next-dev-server.ts:512:19)
    at async invokeRender (node_modules\next\src\server\lib\router-server.ts:284:10)
    at async handleRequest (node_modules\next\src\server\lib\router-server.ts:530:15)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (node_modules\next\src\server\lib\router-server.ts:576:6)
    at async Server.requestListener (node_modules\next\src\server\lib\start-server.ts:146:6)
  23 |         }),
  24 |         async getSessionAndUser(sessionToken) {
> 25 |             const userAndSession = await p.session.findUnique({
     |                                                   ^
  26 |                 where: { sessionToken },
  27 |                 include: { user: true },
  28 |             }); {
  code: undefined
}

this my schema
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  userid     String  @id @default(uuid())
  providerid String  @map("provider_account_id")
  provider   String
  name       String
  username   String? @unique
  email      String? @unique
  nophone    String? @unique
  password   String
  image      String  @default("user.png") @db.Text
  role       String  @default("CUSTOMER")

  ProductDetails ProductDetails[]
  Transactions   Transactions[]

  @@map("users")
}

model ProductDetails {
  productid                String @id @default(uuid())
  userid                   String
  productcode              Int    @unique
  productname              String
  productstatus            String @default("ACTIVE")
  productimagesquare       String @db.Text
  productimagelandscape    String @default("-") @db.Text
  productimageinstructions String @default("-") @db.Text
  productinstructions      String

  User User @relation(fields: [userid], references: [userid], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@map("productdetails")
}

model Transactions {
  trxid         String @id @default(uuid())
  userid        String
  refid         String
  productid     String
  statuspayment String @default("UNPAID")
  statusitem    String @default("UNPAID")

  User User @relation(fields: [userid], references: [userid], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@map("transactions")
}

Here my nextauth options
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";
import type { Adapter } from "next-auth/adapters";
import { prisma } from "./prisma";
import { AuthOptions, User } from "next-auth";
import md5 from "md5";

export const options = {
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma) as Adapter,
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                identifier: { label: "Username/Email", type: "text" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
            },
            async authorize(credentials): Promise<User | null> {
                if (!credentials) {
                    throw new Error("Missing credentials");
                }

                const { identifier, password } = credentials;

                if (!identifier || !password) {
                    throw new Error("Missing identifier or password");
                }

                // Cari user berdasarkan jenis input
                let user;
                if (/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/.test(identifier)) {
                    // Input adalah email
                    user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
                        where: { email: identifier },
                    });
                } else if (/^\d{10,15}$/.test(identifier)) {
                    // Input adalah nomor telepon
                    user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
                        where: { nophone: identifier },
                    });
                } else {
                    // Input adalah username
                    user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
                        where: { username: identifier },
                    });
                }

                // Validate user and password
                if (user && md5(password) === user.password) {
                    return {
                        id: user.userid,
                        userid: user.userid,
                        role: user.role,
                    };
                }

                return null; // If authentication fails
            },
        }),
    ],
    debug: true,
    callbacks: {
        async jwt(params) {
            if (params) {
                params.token.userid = params.user.userid;
                params.token.role = params.user.role;
            }
            return params.token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            session.user.userid = token.userid as string;
            session.user.role = token.role as string;
            return session;
        },
    },
} satisfies AuthOptions;

Here my types
import { DefaultSession, DefaultUser } from "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
    interface User extends DefaultUser {
        id: string;
        userid: string; // Sesuaikan dengan nama kolom ID user Anda
        role: string; // Tambahkan properti role
    }

    interface Session {
        user: {
            userid: string;
            role: string;
        } & DefaultSession["user"];
    }

    interface JWT {
        userid: string;
        role: string;
    }
}

Help me to solve this error
error show when i get useSession.
